# Adding on to function with bool in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, boolean

Beginner here, looking for some help with python!

Right now, I have a function defined that returns a list of lists:

```
def lenumerate(s):
    a = (text.split())
    b = ([len(x) for x in text.split()])
    c = list(zip(a,b))
    print
    return c

text = "But then of course African swallows are nonmigratory"
l = lenumerate(text)
print(l)
```

And it prints out:

```
[('But', 3), ('then', 4), ('of', 2), ('course', 6), ('African', 7), ('swallows', 8), ('are', 3), ('nonmigratory', 12)]
```

Now, I want to write a second version of the function that takes as second argument a boolean (i.e. True or False) called flip. The default value for flip shall be False.

I can reverse the order such that 'nonmigratory' appears at the beginning, but that's not what I want. I want the order preserved, just flipping to (3, "But') all the way through.

I appreciate any help you can offer!

Comment: Why don't you just do `[(len(x), x) for x in text.split())]` at the first place?

Comment: @Kasramvd, even better, just feed `map` into your `zip`, without building an entire list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
def lenumerate(s, flip=False):
    a = text.split()
    b = map(len, a)
    c = zip(a, b) if not flip else zip(b, a)
    return list(c)

text = "But then of course African swallows are nonmigratory"
l = lenumerate(text, True)
print(l)

# [(3, 'But'), (4, 'then'), (2, 'of'), (6, 'course'), (7, 'African'), (8, 'swallows'), (3, 'are'), (12, 'nonmigratory')]
```

**Explanation**

- You only need to apply `split()` once.
- You can feed `map` directly into `zip`. This means more work is done lazily, rather than building unnecessary lists.
- Python supports lazy ternary statements for one-line `if` / `else` constructs.
- A `print` statement with no argument is not useful and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def lenumerate(s, flip=False): ## Default value is False if not provided
    a = (text.split())
    b = ([len(x) for x in text.split()])
    c = list(zip(a,b))

    if list: ## Reverse the pairs if you want to
        c = list(zip(b, a))

    return c

text = "But then of course African swallows are nonmigratory"
l = lenumerate(text)
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Python functions can be called with a single list of arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), instead of multiple individual arguments.

We can use this to make one set of arguments and one reversed set of arguments, depending on the state of `flip`

```
def lenumerate(s, flip=False):
    words = text.split()
    word_lengths = [len(x) for x in text.split()]
    args = [words, word_lengths] if flip else [word_lengths, words]
    return list(zip(*args))


text = "But then of course African swallows are nonmigratory"

print(lenumerate(text))
print(lenumerate(text, True))
```

prints

```
[(3, 'But'), (4, 'then'), (2, 'of'), (6, 'course'), (7, 'African'), (8, 'swallows'), (3, 'are'), (12, 'nonmigratory')]
[('But', 3), ('then', 4), ('of', 2), ('course', 6), ('African', 7), ('swallows', 8), ('are', 3), ('nonmigratory', 12)]
```

Notes

- The parentheses you were using were superfluous
- Try to use speaking variable names, not `a` and `b`

Python's *list comprehensions* make it possible to avoid writing a function in the first place. The above function could be written as:

```
result = [(word, len(word)) for word in text.split()]
print(result)
```